Scilab evaluation polynomial matrix
I would like to know if it is possible to evaluate a polynomial as a matrix in scilab.
For example :
A = floor(10*rand(3,3)); P = poly(A,"x"); horner(P,A) should return the null matrix, but it evaluates P in each coefficient of A instead...
I tried horner(P,A) and P(A) but it doesn't work.

See https://help.scilab.org/docs/2024.1.0/en_US/poly.html

I suppose that you want to check the The Cayley-Hamilton theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) from within Scilab. This is not possible to do this with horner() as this function computes values of a polynomial of a scalar variable. If A is a matrix horner(p,A) computes the values array-wise, not in a matrix sense. However, it is easy to define a function that evaluates polynoms in a matrix sense:
function r = hornerm(p,A)
    r = zeros(A);
    for k = degree(p) : -1: 0
        c = coeff(p, k);
        r = r * A + c * eye();
    end
endfunction

then you have
A = [1 2;3 4]
p = poly(A,"x")
hornerm(p,A)

--> A = [1 2;3 4]

 A = [2x2 double]

   1.   2.
   3.   4.

--> p = poly(A,"x")

 p = [polynomial] of x

  -2 -5x +x^2

--> hornerm(p,A)

 ans = [2x2 double]

   2.220D-16   0.       
   0.          2.220D-16

